# Angular Looping Over Iterator

Tags: angular, typescript, iterator, yield

I have a component with the method:

```
public *numGen(): Iterator<number> {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      yield i;
  }
```

and HTML with:

```
<p *ngFor="let n of numGen()">{{n}}</p>
```

I expect this to generate:

```
<p>0</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

which it does, but it also generates an error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. 
Previous value: 'ngForOf: [object Generator]'. Current value: 'ngForOf: [object Generator]'.
```

Anyone know how to prevent the error being generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the `OnPush` change detection strategy. This will make sure it only checks the bindings when something inside the component has changed by `@Input`, or an event emitted from the template. Which by itself has a big performance improvement, and a more logical pattern of when change detection is triggered.

```
@Component({
  // ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

[see here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-csbptq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

The reason you are seeing this error, is because your method returns a new `Generator` object reference with every change detection.

---

Another way would be to only set the generator when something changes in your component that requires the generator to update. You could use the `ngDoCheck` hook for that. Be aware that this get called quite a lot, although not as often if you use the `OnPush` strategy, which I anyways strongly suggest.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  generator: Iterable<number> = this.numGen();

  multiplier = 1;

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    this.generator = this.numGen();
  }

  times(): void {
    this.multiplier *= 2;
  }

  private *numGen(): Iterable<number> {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {     
      yield i * this.multiplier;
    }
  }
}
```

[example with ngDoCheck](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ejnxml?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

<sub>I do wonder, for what use case are you using the iterator/generator?</sub>

Comment: Ah! I thought I'd tried something similar to the ngOnChanges approach. The ChangeDetectionStrategy works great.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether I need to use this, but I was just experimenting to see if it would work. Ultimately I have a 2D array that I would like to be able to loop through sometimes as a collection of columns and sometimes a collection of rows. Using an iterator seems easier than copying the contents into arrays for columns. I should point out, I think like a C# programmer.

Comment: @JasperKent Alright, then it makes sense :) generators are not usually my first go to solution, just when performance is becoming an issue when working with large datasets, so perhaps you do have the right use case in mind!

Comment: @JasperKent I've updated my answer a bit more, with a solution for the `ngOnChanges` :) (wait, that obviously doesn't work, ignore that)

Comment: @JasperKent ok :p now I found another way